# Number of lines in SQLite string

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite table where a column is of type 'text'. Each item in that column is program code. I want to find out how many lines each text item is. i.e. The following should be 3 lines:

```
program "help"
print "Help"
return.
```

Comment: you will need to count \n and or \r\n

Comment: Is there a way to do it within SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do that only within SQLite as is. SQLite allows for [user defined functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) though, how that works depends on what programming language you're using.

Otherwise you could have a separate column that stores the line count, and update that with whichever language you're using when doing inserts / updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the `\n`s by doing

```sql
LENGTH(TheColumn) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TheColumn, X'0A', '')) + 1
```